# 802.11n (not draft) Wireless access point with gigabit ethernet ports

Tags: wireless-access-point, gigabit-ethernet, dual-band

I looking for a wireless N access point, which isn't 802.11n draft 2.0 so the final certified version of n, with at least 3 gigabit ethernet ports, does anything like that exist. I don't want it to have a router in it, it's just to add wireless capability to a wired network.

Also I just looked in another SO question: [Are there any differences between the 802.11n final and draft specifications?](https://superuser.com/questions/150150/802-11n-vs-802-11n-draft)
and the answer said looking for a router in mid-2010 you should look for "dual-band concurrent 3x3" what is that and are there any models with that as well. 
So:

- Wireless 802.11n (certified, not
  draft)
- at least 3 gigabit ethernet
  ports (but if this isn't possible
  then I can get around that)
- and
  dual-band concurrent 3x3. (whatever
  that is)

Comment: You are unlikely to find a WAP with those specs that also has ethernet and is not a router.  You may have better luck getting a switch and a WAP.

Comment: I thought that may be the case, well then where would I find a WAP with those specs without the ethernet ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current [AirPort](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/) [Extreme](http://store.apple.com/us/go/airportextreme) (whose [Wi-Fi certificate](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/pdf_certificate.php?cid=WFA8066) I linked to in that other SO answer you linked to) meets all your criteria. You can turn off the router functionality in it (technically the NAT and DHCP functionality) and have it act as a simple bridging AP.

It has 3 GigE ports, simultaneous dual-band 3x3, and is final N (these claims are all Wi-Fi certified, well except for the GigE ports).

I've recently been debugging two different problems with two different TrendNet N products, so I'd recommend staying away from that brand.

When it comes to searching for APs that support 3x3 a.k.a. 3 spacial streams, it's probably easiest to search for ones advertised as 450 mbps.

(later...) Hmm, I'm searching around on the Wi-Fi.org certified products listing, and it seems like Apple is ahead of the pack in terms of 3x3 concurrent dual-band APs. The Wi-Fi.org site doesn't allow you to specify 3x3 in the search, so that makes it harder. If I remember I'll try to do some more searching later to find examples from other companies. It would be pretty surprising if no one else did 3x3 *and* simultaneous dual-band, given that it's already been half a year since Apple shipped this revision of the AirPort Extreme and Time Capsule.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one from newegg.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156290)

What are you planning to use this for?

Comment: that looks good, however the question I linked to says that a 3x3 concurrent dual band would mean speeds of up to 450Mbps, I know that's not going to happen in reality but it will mean it's more likely to be faster than a 300Mbps WAP. The product you linked while still good and cheaper than I expected this would be says the max speed is 300Mbps and it looks like a 2x2 (im not 100% what3x3 and 2x2 is)

Comment: @Jonathan - from what I can tell right now, all the 3x3 (3 antenna) systems are on N draft.

Comment: ah ok, well do you have link for one of those?

Comment: Well  they are all routers...No WAPs.  i.e. - http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156286